# LWC - How to populate component when the page just load

Tags: lightning-web-components, customsetting, asynchronous, connected-callback

I'm using `Custom Setting` to remember what user set for that specific setting. So when the component load, it will fetch values from `Custom Setting`.
(1)If there is no value => Column will generate based on user choice.
(2)If there are values, it will set fields based on those values and generate columns.

I'm stuck on the (2) scenario.

HTML code:

```
<template>
    <lightning-combobox name="fieldList" 
        label="Group By" 
        onchange={handleGetPicklistFieldsOptions} 
        options={lstOfPicklistFields} 
        placeholder="Select Field">
    </lightning-combobox>
    <template for:each={groupByHeader} for:item="item">
        <div>                    
            <h1 class="column_heading">
                <span class="slds-truncate_container_25">{item}</span>&nbsp;
            </h1>
        </div>
    </template>
</template>
```

JS code:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track, api } from 'lwc';
import getPicklistTypeFields from '@salesforce/apex/LwcController.getPicklistTypeFields';
import getValueForSelectedPicklistField from '@salesforce/apex/LwcController.getValueForSelectedPicklistField';
import getCustomSetting from '@salesforce/apex/LwcController.getCustomSetting';

export default class lwcComponent extends LightningElement {

@api objectApiName;
@api listViewApi;


    customSettingData = '';
    @track groupByHeader = [];
    groupByValue = '';

    connectedCallback() {
        getCustomSetting({
            sobjectType: this.objectApiName,
            listviewApi: this.listViewApi})
            .then((result) => {
                this.customSettingData = result;
                this.groupByValue = this.customSettingData.GroupField__c;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('Error***', error);
            })

        //I call this method here to generate the column when the page just load
        // but it did not work

        getValueForSelectedPicklistField({ 
            strObjectName: this.objectApiName, 
            selectedField: this.groupByValue })
            .then((result) => {
                if (result) {
                    if(this.groupByHeader.length == 0)
                        this.groupByHeader = [];
                    for (let key in result) {
                        this.groupByHeader.push(key);
                    }
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('Error in getting pickist values')
            })
    }
    
    @track lstOfPicklistFields = [];
    wireAllPickListRes = '';
    @wire(getPicklistTypeFields, { strObjectName : '$objectApiName' })
    wireAllPickList(result) {
        this.wireAllPickListRes = result;
        let {error, data} = result;
        if(data) {
            this.lstOfPicklistFields = [];
            for (let key in data) {
                this.lstOfPicklistFields.push({ label: key, value: data[key] });
            }
        }
        if(error) {
            console.log('Error in getting picklist fields');
        }
    }

    //this is the process when user have not set any value

    handleGetPicklistFieldsOptions(event) { 
        this.groupByValue = event.detail.value;
        this.getPicklistValuesForSelectedPicklistField();
    }
    
    async getPicklistValuesForSelectedPicklistField() {
        await getValueForSelectedPicklistField({ 
            strObjectName: this.objectApiName, 
            selectedField: this.groupByValue })
        .then((result) => {
          if (result) {
            if(this.groupByHeader.length == 0)
                this.groupByHeader = [];
            for (let key in result) {
                this.groupByHeader.push(key);
            }
          } 
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log('Error in getting pickist values')
        })
    }
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getValueForSelectedPicklistField` will be called in `connectedCallback` before `this.customSettingData` has been set, because of how asynchronous code works. Let's look at a short example.

```
let fn = (msg) => {
    console.log(`before ${msg}`);
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(msg)));
}
fn("function 1").then((msg) => console.log(`Function 1 returns ${msg}`));
fn("function 2").then((msg) => console.log(`Function 2 returns ${msg}`));
```

When we run this code, we'll see:

```
before function 1
before function 2
Function 1 returns function 1
Function 2 returns function 2
```

That's what's going on with your code. You need to wait for the first call to complete before calling the second one. The easiest way to get there is to use async/await.

```
  async connectedCallback() {
    let result;
    // get the custom setting data first
    result = await getCustomSetting({
      sobjectType: this.objectApiName,
      listviewApi: this.listViewApi,
    });
    // this runs after the custom setting data has been retrieved
    this.customSettingData = result;
    this.groupByValue = this.customSettingData.GroupField__c;
    // get the value for the selected picklist field
    result = await getValueForSelectedPicklistField({
      strObjectName: this.objectApiName,
      selectedField: this.groupByValue,
    });
    // this runs after the value for the selected picklist field has been retrieved
    if (result) {
      if (this.groupByHeader.length == 0) this.groupByHeader = [];
      for (let key in result) {
        this.groupByHeader.push(key);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for sharing your knowledge! It works now.